# Use sed to extract ascii hex string from a file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, hex, ascii

I have a file that looks like this:

```
$ some random
$ text
00ab2c3f03$ and more
random text
1a2bf04$ more text
blah blah
```

and the code that looks like this:

```
sed -ne 's/\(.*\)$ and.*/\1/p'  "file.txt" > "output1.txt"
sed -ne 's/\(.*\)$ more.*/\1/p' "file.txt" > "output2.txt"
```

That gives me this `00ab2c3f03` and this `1a2bf04`

So it extracts anything from the beginning of the line to the `shell prompt` and stores it in the file, twice for two different instances.

The problem is that the file sometimes looks like this:

```
/dir # some random
/dir # text
00ab2c3f03/dir # and more
random text
345fabd0067234234/dir # more text
blah blah
```

And I want to make an universal extractor that either:

- extracts data from the beginning of the line to the '$' OR '/' characters
- intelligently extracts random amount of random `hex` data from the beginning of the line up to the first `non-hex` digit

But I'm not so good with `sed` to actually think of an easy solution by myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the output like this,

```
$ cat file
$ some random
$ text
00ab2c3f03$ and more
random text
1a2bf04$ more text
blah blah
/dir # some random
/dir # text
00ab2c3f03/dir # and more
random text
345fabd0067234234/dir # more text
blah blah

$ sed -ne 's/\([a-f0-9]*\).* and more.*/\1/p' file
00ab2c3f03
00ab2c3f03

$ sed -ne 's/\([a-f0-9]*\).* more text.*/\1/p' file
1a2bf04
345fabd0067234234
```

You could try the below GNU `sed` command also. Because `/` present in your input, i changed the sed delimiter to `~`,

```
$ sed -nr 's~([a-f0-9]*)\/*\$*.* and more.*~\1~p' file
00ab2c3f03
00ab2c3f03

$ sed -nr 's~([a-f0-9]*)\/*\$*.* more text.*~\1~p' file
1a2bf04
345fabd0067234234
```

Explanation:

- `([a-f0-9]*)` - Captures all the hexdigits and stored it into a group.
- OP said there may be chance of `/` or `$` symbol present just after the hex digits so the regex  should be `\/*\$*`(`/` zero or more times, `$` zero or more times) after capturing group.
- First command only works on the lines which contains the strings `and more`.
- And the second one only works on the lines which contain `more text` because op want the two outputs in two different files.

Comment: Thank you for a realy good explanation, now I would like to ask you for help with very similar problem: only one line in the file contains only hex characters, how do I extract that? I tried `sed -ne 's/^\([A-F0-9]*\)$/\1/p' file` I usied line start and line end (^&) as delimiters, but I am obviously missing something...

Answer (score 0):

This seems better to me:

```
sed -nr 's#([[:xdigit:]]+)[$/].*#\1#p' file
```